# mvn go-offline trying to download dependencies not in dependency tree

Tags: maven, log4j, artifactory, maven-dependency-plugin

I have a maven build that fails on executing `mvn go-offline`, because it tries to download  `log4j-core:2.11.2` - a version which has been removed from my company's Artifactory due to the Log4Shell vulnerability.

But I can't figure out why my project is trying to download that specific version of `log4j-core`. I have explicitly defined a `log4j-core:2.17.1` dependency in my pom, and `log4j-core:2.11.2` is nowhere in my project's dependency tree. In addition, running `mvn install` works fine and doesn't require `log4j-core:2.11.2`: only the `mvn go-offline` command thinks it needs `2.11.2`.

The project set up with a parent pom, like this:

```
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    ...
    <dependencies>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
     </dependency>
     ...
    </dependencies>
```

Result of executing `mvn -X dependency:go-offline`:

```
[DEBUG] Resolving artifact org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:pom:2.11.2 from [central (https://artifacts.mycompany.int/artifactory/maven-all, default, releases), snapshots (https://artifacts.mycompany.int/artifactory/maven-all, default, releases+snapshots), apache.snapshots (https://repository.apache.org/snapshots, default, snapshots)]
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://artifacts.mycompany.int/artifactory/maven-all/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.11.2/log4j-core-2.11.2.pom
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file /mybuilddir/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.11.2/log4j-core-2.11.2.pom.lastUpdated
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.11.2 is missing, no dependency information available
[DEBUG] Resolving artifact org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.11.2 from [central (https://artifacts.mycompany.int/artifactory/maven-all, default, releases), snapshots (https://artifacts.mycompany.int/artifactory/maven-all, default, releases+snapshots)]
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://artifacts.mycompany.int/artifactory/maven-all/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.11.2/log4j-core-2.11.2.jar
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file /mybuilddir/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.11.2/log4j-core-2.11.2.jar.lastUpdated
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:go-offline (default-cli) on project myproject: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.11.2 in central (https://artifacts.mycompany.int/artifactory/maven-all) -> [Help 1]
```

Result of executing `mvn -X org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.3.0:tree -Dverbose=true` (the only version of `log4j-core` that shows up is `2.17.1`. Version `2.11.2` is not mentioned anywhere in this tree):

```
[DEBUG] com.mycompany:myproject:jar:1.7.0
...
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.17.1:compile
...
```

I cannot understand why my pom is trying to download a dependency version not listed in the tree. Is it some sort of transitive dependency that is not being printed out in the tree? If so, how do I get the dependency tree to print it, as well as which artifact is bringing it in? Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1):

`dependency:go-offline` try to resolve and download all dependencies used in your project ... but also try to resolve all Maven plugins used in project and their dependencies

Also `dependency:tree` show what you use in project.

So even if your project have no dependencies to `log4j-core:2.11.2` some of plugins used to build project can have it ...

Please examine output of:

```
mvn dependency:resolve-plugins
```